# Symbology count in database form

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology

I am working on a file which contains points from different areas of country. I have symbolized points. I want the feature count of respective area in a database form in .dbf file or excel etc. How can i get this count number (shown in figure) the dbf file.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to run a [Frequency](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000001w000000) on the feature. Just select your "Constituen" field for the frequency field in the input and then  join the output on the same field.

Although it is an extra step to the summary statistics, it will definitely work on a text field, and should work on any field type you throw at it.

Comment: thx a lot it has been done just the way i wanted.. :) Though I used programming techniques to solve it but this is really helpful... :)

Comment: Note that [**Frequency**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000001w000000) tool requires an Advanced license.

Answer (score 4):

To do this I would use the **[Summary Statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000001z000000)** tool which can be used with a Basic license and has a COUNT option.

In the graphic below I want to count how many times each value of a field called CLASSIFICA occurs so I use the COUNT statistic on the FID (object ID) field using CLASSIFICA as the case field.

[image]

The output has a field called FREQUENCY that is the count of each unique value found for the CLASSIFICA field.

[image]

Comment: The type i want to go along is "text" whereas it does not go with text... My data comes from field and I have a mixture of alpha numeric data that also includes a "-" in that...

Comment: @Ade'l - as you will see above there is no problem using a text field with Summary Statistics to count unique values.

Comment: I may be experiencing this as I am using 9.3 version... ill try this on version 10 as well... :)

Comment: I did this lots at 9.3 too so am pretty confident it works there too.

Comment: ok, what I am doing here is "adding a field OID_1" as it does not give me the option to select the FID field. I tried this field with different data types e.g long, int, double and etxt field was already of no use! even then it gives me an error 000800, The value is not a matter of SUM|MIN|MAX|COUNT etc. I used the field emplty and also tried after populating it wid FID values... Hope it give u some clue where I am mistaken... :)

Comment: Plz refer to above comment...

Comment: Are you saying that you have an input shapefile for which FID does not show up in the list of statistics fields? If so, was the shapefile created by ArcGIS or something else and can you perhaps post a screenshot of its attribute table?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8953/discussion-between-adel-and-polygeo)

Comment: I have sent u a screenshot in the chat... u there...?

Comment: I viewed the screenshot of your attribute table this morning and it looks like a normal shapefile to me.  Are you saying that the FID field does not show up in the pick list of statistics fields on the tool dialog? If so, was the shapefile created by ArcGIS or something else?  Since you are suspicious of 9.3, have you had a chance to test my procedure at 10.x?

Comment: Hi @PolyGeo: ur right, as i previously told u the procedure of how i added this data. I am pasting my response for u again here "I had this data came from field in csv format... i used .xls file n called its coordinates via "add xy data" to make it more clear I exported data n created a shapefile using ArcGIS n used it for further operations... :)" No i haven't tried it using 10.x

Comment: OK - I am going to give up on this one because I can offer no explanation as to why my procedure would not work for you at ArcGIS 9.3 (and probably earlier versions), 10.0 or 10.1.

Comment: That would still be very kind of u... No worries as the method given by eselgem is pretty effictive n just the way I wanted... :) Thx anyways.